# sourceloader - No configuration found in the configured sources

Tags: logstash

when I run the command `sudo bin/logstash -f logstash.conf` it appears this error

```
[ERROR] 2018-04-05 10:22:32.872 [Ruby-0-Thread-1: /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/stud-0.0.23/lib/stud/task.rb:22] sourceloader - No configuration found in the configured sources.
```

I don't know what to do anymore. Logstash reinstalled did not help. Changing the logstash config also did not help.

Who can tell me how to fix this problem?

Here is my current config:

```
input {
  file {
    type => "rails logs"
    path => "/home/user/apps/demo/log/logstash_development.log"
    codec =>   json {
      charset => "UTF-8"
    }
  }
}

output {
  # Print each event to stdout.
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }

  elasticsearch {
    # Setting 'embedded' will run  a real elasticsearch server inside logstash.
    # This option below saves you from having to run a separate process just
    # for ElasticSearch, so you can get started quicker!
    embedded => true
  }
}
```

Comment: Share the debug log. Also use the  following command to test your config file  

bin/logstash -f logstash.conf --configtest

Comment: Note also that the param `embedded` is deprecated for the elasticsearch output plugin.

Answer (score 3):

The `logstash.conf` file is inside the *config* folder, not in *bin*.

Use a command like `W:\logstash\bin>logstash -f .\..\config\logstash.conf`.

Comment: As per my recent, experience, the `logstash.conf` file is in main directory of logstash just in case above answer does not work

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the above issue using the below command in the Windows system.

**`logstash-simple.conf`**

```
input {
   file {
     type => "rails logs"
     path => "E:/Hadoop_Win/ELK/elk-example.log"
     start_position => "beginning"
   }
}
output {
  stdout {}
}
```

Use the below command to start logstash service.

```
E:\Hadoop_Win\ELK\logstash-8.0.0\bin>logstash -f E:\Hadoop_Win\ELK\logstash-8.7.0\config\logstash-simple.conf
```

OR

```
E:\Hadoop_Win\ELK\logstash-8.7.0\bin>logstash.bat -f E:\Hadoop_Win\ELK\logstash-8.7.0\config\logstash-simple.conf --path.settings=E:\Hadoop_Win\ELK\logstash-8.7.0\config\
```

Where **E:\Hadoop_Win\ELK\logstash-8.7.0\config** is the folder that contains your **pipelines.yml**  and other configuration files.